# Is the approach right?

Tags: java, fileutils, apache-commons-io

I have some few files of different extensions like .rdf, .pkg,.fmb,.sql and .ldt.
In these files I have to find that some specific keywords are present or not.
So for this purpose I used two ways.

1st approach

```
String content = FileUtils.readFileToString(file);
```

2nd approach

```
byte[] b = FileUtils.readFileToByteArray(fl);
                String read = new String(b);
```

now after getting these strings I search the keywords.
The problem is I'm not sure whether from these approaches I'll be able to scan the entire file or not. Since those files are not text files so When I print these Strings in console , half the text is no readable. So I'm not sure whether this approach gives me the correct result or not.
Please tell me how these two methods work. And will it give  me all the keywords present in those files or not.
Please guide.

Comment: It's open-source. Download the source code and read it.

Comment: In which library is your `FileUtil`?

Comment: I'm pretty sure this is Apache's commons-io.

Comment: yes it is org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils

Comment: If the input files are not text files, neither approach will work in all cases, but both might well work in most cases, depending on the binary format.

Answer (score 0):

If there is only one line in file, you can use the 1st approach:

```
String content = FileUtils.readFileToString(file);
```

if there are more lines, you can use this approach:

```
String sCurrentLine;
br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("C:\\testing.txt"));
while ((sCurrentLine = br.readLine()) != null) {
    System.out.println(sCurrentLine);
}
```